# Using string replace to insert the string '$_' in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with string replacement in powershell. Please consider the following expression:

```
"replaceTarget: %rep" -replace '%rep','$_'
```

I expect the result of this expression to be:

```
replaceTarget: $_
```

but instead, it is

```
replaceTarget: replaceTarget: $rep
```

I assume it is because the replacement string `'$_'` has some other meaning in the `replace` function.

How can I escape the input string so that `$_` can be passed in without being evaluated?

Comment: The first string gets expanded to `replaceTarget: [whatever is inside $rep]` - but you're trying to replace the literal string `$rep`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've edited the question to clarify the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you coud use the .net replace function like this :
`` 'replaceTarget: $rep'.replace("`$rep",'$_') ``

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I tried `[Regex]::replace` and that had the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

try with this:

```
'replaceTarget: %rep' -replace '%rep','$$_'
```

Comment: Nice.$ also act  as an espace character ?? Never se en that before!

Comment: really strange behaviour : `PS>$test  ` -> VariableIsUndefined.  `PS>"$$test"    ` -> $testtest

Comment: @Kayasax  in your last case $$ is expanded as the last command you enter. try >cls >"$$magic". In there `-replace` the double $$ work as an escape but in reality is just a rule of expanding system, I cannot find the original document but if I find I'll give feedback here!

Comment: I still don't understand this behavior, from about_automatic_variables : "$$ Contains the last token in the last line received by the session.". cls>"$$magic" should be null or contains clsmagic to my understanding, not magicmagic...

Comment: @Kayasax  if I digit at powershell prompt `cls` <enter> then `"$$magic"` <enter> it returns `clsmagic`. Different is if used after the `-replace 'xx','$$'` where any `xx` is replaced by a single dollar sign. Do you follow now?

Comment: sorry I wrote $$magic without quotes then "$$magic" wich has confused me

Comment: @Kayasax ok, maybe you wrote 'magic' and enter once. Anyway, we can say that  in powershell for  escape a `$` in the replaced part of a `-replace` sintax you need to double the `$` ;)